# #if APPCLIP doesn't recognise APPCLIP target

Tags: xcode, swiftui, apple-appclips

I created a new APPCLIP target and shared the same file between the main app and the app clip app but when I try to give add some specific code with #if APPCLIP that never get called, and I'm definitely running the AppClip target.

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you expect. `#if APPCLIP` is a compile-time test. The compiler doesn't know what target you are compiling. It knows about Active Compilation Conditions but you have not proven, with your screen shot, that you have one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add `APPCLIP` to your `Active Compilation Conditions` for the App Clip target:

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks that was it. I was expecting this to be automatically set when adding the AppClip target

Comment: amazing answer, thank you!